# A hinge door stopper that won't break easily

Tags: doors, hinges

I have a door which can only be controlled by a hinge mounted stopper. So far I've only used this kind: [image: hinge door stopper]
but it is not sturdy enough and it breaks every so often.

I'd like to know what other options I have of more solid hinge stoppers.
I thought of the possibility of using more than one, but I would like a better one.
Also, has anyone used [this other type](http://thequickdoorhanger.com/doorsaver3-bumper-less-adjustable-hinge-pin-door-stop/)? If so, what do you think of it?
[image]

Comment: Do you have pictures of the door and surrounding area? Depending on the layout, I may know of an option.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk No I don't and I'm not going to be able to take a picture any time soon.

Comment: WHat if you mount three of those, one on each hinge?

Answer (score 3):

Better answer is to use a door stop that stops the door rather than the hinge. Anything that mounts at the hinge will eventually pull the hinge screws out or bend the hinge leaves or both.

Comment: As I mentions in my question, that's not an option. I would've done that if it would've been possible.

Comment: Impossible and "I haven't thought of a way to do that" are pretty indistinguishable until you think of a way to do that. There are many ways to stop a door - any that are on the hinge side are subject to HUGE mechanical forces due to leverage. Simplest option may be an arm-type **door closer**, which mounts to the top of the door, and also acts as a stop. A simple sliding bar in the same position would act as a stop only, but closers are easier to find off the shelf.

Comment: "eventually" is on the order of decades unless you've got a household full of irate door-slammers.